# Finding maxima in 2D matrix along certain dimension with indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, indexing, max

I have a `<206x193>` matrix `A`. It contains the values of a parameter at 206 different locations at 193 time steps. I am interested in the maximum value at each location over all times as well as the corresponding indices. I have another matrix `B` with the same dimensions of `A` and I'm interested in values for each location at the time that `A`'s value at that location was maximal.

I've tried `[max_val pos] = max(A,[],2)`, which gives the right maximum values, but `A(pos)` does not equal `max_val`.

How exactly does this function work?

I tried a smaller example as well. Still I don't understand the meaning of the indices....

```
>> H

H(:,:,1) =

     1     2
     3     4

H(:,:,2) =

     5     6
     7     8

>> [val pos] = max(H,[],2)

val(:,:,1) =

     2
     4

val(:,:,2) =

     6
     8

pos(:,:,1) =

     2
     2

pos(:,:,2) =

     2
     2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indices in `idx` represent the index of the max value in the corresponding row. You can use `sub2ind` to create a linear index if you want to test if `A(pos)=max_val`

```
A=rand(206, 193);
[max_val, idx]=max(A, [], 2);
A_max=A(sub2ind(size(A), (1:size(A,1))', idx));
```

Similarly, you can access the values of B with:

```
B_Amax=B(sub2ind(size(A), (1:size(A,1))', idx));
```

From your example:

```
H(:,:,2) =

 5     6
 7     8

[val pos] = max(H,[],2)

val(:,:,2) =

 6
 8

pos(:,:,2) =

 2
 2
```

The reason why `pos(:,:,2)` is `[2; 2]` is because the maximum is at position 2 for both rows.

Answer (score 0):

max is a primarily intended for use with vectors. In normal mode, even the multi-dimensional arrays are treated as a series of vectors along which the max function is applied.

So, to get the values in B at each location at the time where A is maximum, you should

```
// find the maximum values and positions in A
[c,i] = max(A, [], 2);
// iterate along the first dimension, to retrieve the corresponding values in B
C = [];
for k=1:size(A,1)
    C(k) = B(k,i(k));
end
```

You can refer to @Jigg's answer for a more concise way of creating matrix C